# Meaningful legend when using scale_[...]_identity

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I have a data frame that explicitly contains `aesthetic` information explicitly:

```
df <- structure(list(
  tpr = c(0.57, 0.1, 0.02, 0, 0, 1, 0.11, 0.03, 0.01, 0, 1, 0.1, 0.04, 0.01, 0, 1, 0.12, 0.03, 0, 0),
  ppv = c(0.07, 0.3, 0.54, 0.38, NaN, 0.03, 0.24, 0.28, 0.5, NaN, 0.03, 0.14, 0.28, 0.25, NaN, 0.03, 0.22, 0.36, 0.3, NaN),
  model = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("model1", "model2", "model3", "model4"), class = "factor"),
  alpha = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
  col = c("steelblue", "steelblue", "steelblue", "steelblue", "steelblue", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red"),
  size = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)),
  .Names = c("tpr", "ppv", "model", "alpha", "col", "size"),
  class = c("data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

I'm plotting my data using

```
ggplot(
    ddf,
    aes(x= tpr, y = ppv,  group = model, col = col, alpha = alpha, size = size)
    ) +
    geom_line()+
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,1,by=.1), minor_breaks = seq(0,1, by = .05))+
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,1, by = .1), limits = c(0,1))+
    scale_color_identity()+
    scale_alpha_identity()+
    scale_size_identity()+
    theme_minimal()
```

[image: plot1]

However, I can't figure out how to add a *single* legend that shows *all* the aesthetics with the corresponding group label. I'm expecting something like

[image] 
but with the correct aesthetics per group (i.e. `color`, `size`, `alpha` in this case).

I'm aware of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31610202/4755970), but I would like to stay away from specifying manual scales and instead use the scales provided within the data itself.

Is this possible in `ggplot2`? How?

Comment: If you use `scale_colour_identity(guide="legend")` you will get a legend, but the levels will be labeled "red" and "steelblue". So then, is there some way to designate labels of "model1", "model2" etc.? I don't know, but if it's possible it will certainly be just as complicated as using `scale_*_manual` with named vectors of values. By the way, the `guide="legend"` thing triggers an error if used with alpha and size scales, not clear why that should be a problem.

Comment: Have you tried using base plotting functions? It's easy to construct a legend manually with base, but really hard (or not possible) with ggplot2.

Comment: @bdemarest Regarding "_triggers an error_", I posted [an issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2112).

Comment: Thanks for the input. I had also played around with the `guide` and `label` things (and encountered the same error :) ) but couldn't get it to work as I wanted either.

I used the `scale_*_manual` way for now (including making sure stuff appears in the right order etc).
I guess explicitly supplying the aesthetics in the data is simply not a very GoG-way of doing things, nevertheless I think creating legends for (multiple) `scale_*_identity`s should be possible. @Henrik, thanks for opening the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this, maybe.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = tpr, y = ppv, colour = model, linetype = model))+
geom_line()
```