# Can someone help me properly set up my ggplot legend with multiple defined aesthetics?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, aesthetics

I would love to have a clearer legend in my ggplot (below). Specifically, the point shapes overlapping with line geometries is not clear. **It would be nice to have one legend for the predictive data (linetypes, ribbon fills, color) and another for the raw data (point shapes, color).**

After playing around I managed to separate the two groups, but I can't find a way to have group colors applied to both legends. Furthermore, it seems that even when I group linetype and fill together using the same labs() name, there is still a grey fill on the point shape legend. This is a lot of information but the takeaway is after much playing around, I can't get the legend to behave.

I have provided my code and datasets; maybe someone could help me out?

Here's my ggplot:

[image: My plot]

and here's the code that generated it:

```
ggplot(predict.df, aes(x = x, y = predicted, colour = group, shape = group, linetype = group)) +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high, fill = group), alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_jitter(data = raw, mapping = aes(x = x, y = response), width = 8, height = 0) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Sample date", breaks = c(0, 35, 70, 105), labels = c("June 26", "July 31", "Sept 4", "Oct 9")) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Viral load (virus/\u00b5g DNA)", breaks = c(0, 1, 2, 3), labels = c(1, 10, 100, 1000)) +
  theme_pubr(legend = "right") +
  labs(color = "Locus", shape = "Locus", fill = "Locus", linetype = "Locus") +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2")
```

Here are the two plugged in data frames:

```
> dput(predict.df)
structure(list(x = c(0, 0, 0, 35, 35, 35, 70, 70, 70, 105, 105, 
105), predicted = c(1.76102123590214, 0.37702177715769, 0.502111657963439, 
2.16765850174448, 1.13876128504506, 0.72723857556493, 2.57429576758682, 
1.90050079293243, 0.95236549316642, 2.98093303342917, 2.66224030081979, 
1.17749241076791), std.error = c(0.210212347913819, 0.167399741123415, 
0.183879503224061, 0.145514809621925, 0.106824868721082, 0.108685998504236, 
0.121276566028898, 0.176399586908295, 0.18802919804674, 0.15744703287395, 
0.295192239702551, 0.323169724522022), conf.low = c(1.34901260488545, 
0.0489243135344682, 0.141714454149163, 1.88245471566831, 0.929388389698517, 
0.514217932872852, 2.33659806600149, 1.55476395570442, 0.58383503695286, 
2.67234251952353, 2.08367414248708, 0.544091389811016), conf.high = c(2.17302986691883, 
0.705119240780912, 0.862508861777715, 2.45286228782065, 1.3481341803916, 
0.940259218257007, 2.81199346917216, 2.24623763016043, 1.32089594937998, 
3.2895235473348, 3.24080645915251, 1.8108934317248), group = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Basal", 
"Medial", "Distal"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -12L
), class = c("ggeffects", "data.frame"), legend.labels = c("Basal", 
"Medial", "Distal"), x.is.factor = "0", continuous.group = FALSE, rawdata = structure(list(
    response = c(2.23667815433731, 0.585725623985699, 0, 2.63585811315419, 
    0, 0, 2.33374975605124, 0, 0.884942436609621, 1.16286703780418, 
    1.06709808539313, 0, 0.890758164061038, 0, 0.639404117570214, 
    2.47790759499121, 0, 0, 2.14524220682092, 0, 0, 1.9740589910418, 
    0, 0, 0, 1.25516666996646, 2.66751722923715, 0, 0, 1.92521830152371, 
    0.903597044237988, 0.945099129999455, 2.6442228874261, 2.58142029334097, 
    0, 2.32153495885343, 1.3801896215756, 1.02489379026788, 2.05743286900869, 
    1.11074999614049, 0.860338006570994, 1.55767122072119, 0.989126434016326, 
    1.21554496604287, 2.14770759585995, 1.92492507723203, 1.86644529881602, 
    2.40375462277453, 1.34200834355252, 1.14456300882461, 2.25413032451885, 
    1.05881158464742, 0.880851309461926, 2.72704842428525, 1.01414176946023, 
    1.13102772933728, 2.78511309801747, 2.0899051114394, 1.02716459664481, 
    1.90825217816864, 0.791001136920094, 2.27946840305546, 2.48278954016739, 
    0.940828612330139, 2.20441891726465, 1.95118485766815, 1.01752434498353, 
    1.22992186490351, 1.18351341124408, 1.17491390968833, 1.54441258580579, 
    1.24401572811876, 0.878566226876958, 2.35327316999556, 2.13603849721832, 
    2.29146399657572, 2.41044404137815, 2.21254419548501, 0.826472233221594, 
    2.20421121140994, 1.57587890647473, 0.897437484440932, 2.34225098899079, 
    2.38136059256142, 0.972352525321007, 1.6028414421383, 2.20134373839759, 
    0.810820367137012, 2.77026731894286, 2.29241135584685, 0.57988940596851, 
    3.71170452590752, 3.4954877455041, 3.18504082301818, 3.67423352412794, 
    2.98414705180641, 0.141639163861031, 2.41217775364379, 0.51123419122885, 
    0.476456687670469, 3.36887472776869, 3.02081502150107, 0.513445669923521, 
    3.63514892267612, 3.51925820816477, 3.40746252696249, 3.27998529166281, 
    0.623505586942313, 0.798307744015814, 3.27752745673065, 3.18652456493964, 
    0.184008911262831, 3.18983391030149, 2.77631390383718, 0.395623039048979, 
    3.46567596502934, 3.02900875924267, 0.433385505287688), x = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 
    35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 
    35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 
    70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 
    70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 
    105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 
    105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105), group = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Basal", 
    "Medial", "Distal"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-118L)), title = "Predicted values of log.Virus.Particles", x.title = "Date", y.title = "log.Virus.Particles", legend.title = "Locus", constant.values = list(
    Study.ID = "0 (population-level)"), terms = c("Date", "Locus"
), original.terms = c("Date", "Locus"), at.list = list(Date = c(0, 
35, 70, 105), Locus = c("Basal", "Medial", "Distal")), prediction.interval = FALSE, ci.lvl = 0.95, family = "gaussian", link = "identity", logistic = "0", is.trial = "0", fitfun = "lm", model.name = "model1")
```

and

```
>  dput(raw)
structure(list(response = c(2.23667815433731, 0.585725623985699, 
0, 2.63585811315419, 0, 0, 2.33374975605124, 0, 0.884942436609621, 
1.16286703780418, 1.06709808539313, 0, 0.890758164061038, 0, 
0.639404117570214, 2.47790759499121, 0, 0, 2.14524220682092, 
0, 0, 1.9740589910418, 0, 0, 0, 1.25516666996646, 2.66751722923715, 
0, 0, 1.92521830152371, 0.903597044237988, 0.945099129999455, 
2.6442228874261, 2.58142029334097, 0, 2.32153495885343, 1.3801896215756, 
1.02489379026788, 2.05743286900869, 1.11074999614049, 0.860338006570994, 
1.55767122072119, 0.989126434016326, 1.21554496604287, 2.14770759585995, 
1.92492507723203, 1.86644529881602, 2.40375462277453, 1.34200834355252, 
1.14456300882461, 2.25413032451885, 1.05881158464742, 0.880851309461926, 
2.72704842428525, 1.01414176946023, 1.13102772933728, 2.78511309801747, 
2.0899051114394, 1.02716459664481, 1.90825217816864, 0.791001136920094, 
2.27946840305546, 2.48278954016739, 0.940828612330139, 2.20441891726465, 
1.95118485766815, 1.01752434498353, 1.22992186490351, 1.18351341124408, 
1.17491390968833, 1.54441258580579, 1.24401572811876, 0.878566226876958, 
2.35327316999556, 2.13603849721832, 2.29146399657572, 2.41044404137815, 
2.21254419548501, 0.826472233221594, 2.20421121140994, 1.57587890647473, 
0.897437484440932, 2.34225098899079, 2.38136059256142, 0.972352525321007, 
1.6028414421383, 2.20134373839759, 0.810820367137012, 2.77026731894286, 
2.29241135584685, 0.57988940596851, 3.71170452590752, 3.4954877455041, 
3.18504082301818, 3.67423352412794, 2.98414705180641, 0.141639163861031, 
2.41217775364379, 0.51123419122885, 0.476456687670469, 3.36887472776869, 
3.02081502150107, 0.513445669923521, 3.63514892267612, 3.51925820816477, 
3.40746252696249, 3.27998529166281, 0.623505586942313, 0.798307744015814, 
3.27752745673065, 3.18652456493964, 0.184008911262831, 3.18983391030149, 
2.77631390383718, 0.395623039048979, 3.46567596502934, 3.02900875924267, 
0.433385505287688), x = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 35, 35, 35, 
35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 
35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 
70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 
70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 
105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 
105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105), group = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Basal", "Medial", "Distal"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-118L))
```

**Edit 1, addressing MrFlick's comment**

I tried the suggestions at the link you provided:

```
## Model with predictive slopes
ggplot(predict.df, aes(x = x, y = predicted, colour = group, shape = group, linetype = group)) +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high, fill = group), alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_jitter(data = raw, mapping = aes(x = x, y = response), width = 8, height = 0) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Sample date", breaks = c(0, 35, 70, 105), labels = c("June 26", "July 31", "Sept 4", "Oct 9")) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Viral load (virus/\u00b5g DNA)", breaks = c(0, 1, 2, 3), labels = c(1, 10, 100, 1000)) +
  theme_pubr(legend = "right") +
  scale_color_brewer(name = "Raw data", palette = "Dark2") +
  scale_fill_brewer(name = "Prediction", palette = "Dark2") +
  scale_linetype_discrete(name = "Prediction") +
  scale_shape_discrete(name = "Raw data")
```

And ended up with:
[image: Plot 2]

This is more or less where I end up no matter what I try.

Comment: Rather than `print()`ing your data, please share a `dput()` tp put your data in a more [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also see this question for a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23343333/ggplot2-shape-color-and-linestyle-into-one-legend. You should be able to get separate legends if you give them separate names.

Comment: Thanks for the advice MrFlick. I changed it to ```dput()```. I've experimented with the advice from the linked response as well as others--it works with the exception that I cannot get colors to show up in both legends. In the linked example he has no aes in the base layer and instead has aes calls in the geom_ layers. I'm not sure that the structure of my data would allow me to do the same thing easily

Comment: Oh you want color to be used in two different legends? That's not something ggplot likes very much.

Comment: I'm starting to see that. I added an edit to my question showing where I end up when I try the solution you linked.

Comment: @MrFlick the ability to change `guides` in the later versions of ggplot makes it possible to put color in multiple legends, though as far as I can tell, you need to re-specify the colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can get what you want by altering the `guides`:

```r
ggplot(predict.df, aes(x = x, y = predicted, colour = group, 
                       shape = group, linetype = group)) +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high, fill = group), alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_jitter(data = raw, mapping = aes(x = x, y = response), width = 8, height = 0) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Sample date", breaks = c(0, 35, 70, 105), 
                     labels = c("June 26", "July 31", "Sept 4", "Oct 9")) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Viral load (virus/\u00b5g DNA)", 
                     breaks = c(0, 1, 2, 3), 
                     labels = c(1, 10, 100, 1000)) +
  theme_pubr(legend = "right") +
  labs(color = "Raw", shape = "Raw", fill = "Locus", linetype = "Locus") +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(name = "Locus", 
                             override.aes = list(
                                    fill = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(3, "Dark2"),
                                    alpha = 0.1)),
         linetype = guide_legend(name = "Locus", 
                                 override.aes = list(
                                    color = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(3, "Dark2"))),
         shape = guide_legend(name = "Raw", override.aes = list(size = 3)),
         color = guide_legend(name = "Raw", 
                              override.aes = list(fill = NA,
                              linetype = 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: This is awesome, thank you. It seems I need to familiarize myself with guides.